# Simple interactive visualization of a network using R

Tags: r, plot

If have a simple example (for data see below) which I can visualize as follows:

[![network][1]][1]

My problem is, that I would like to use **popups** to display further information (which does not fit in the graph). The question is: How can I do this?
I found many stuff but I was not able to make the example work, which might be caused, that I never programmed in Java. I should also say, that I don't need fancy/complicated 3D stuff. Just a popup would do the job!

Any help is highly appreciated!

Links:

- [presentation](http://curleylab.psych.columbia.edu/netviz/netviz1.html#/): I cannot reproduce the example and I think that I don't need that much.
- [tutorial](http://kateto.net/network-visualization) chapter 7.1: I cannot reproduce the example

Here is the data

```
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)

nodes <- c("cool_fun", "mysum", "mydot", "myfun", "stupid_fun")
list_edges <- structure(list(
  cool_fun = structure(list(edges = character(0), 
                            weights = numeric(0)), 
                       .Names = c("edges", "weights")), 
  mysum = structure(list(edges = character(0), 
                         weights = numeric(0)), 
                    .Names = c("edges", "weights")), 
  mydot = structure(list(edges = character(0), 
                         weights = numeric(0)), 
                    .Names = c("edges", "weights")), 
  myfun = structure(list(edges = c("mysum", "mydot"), 
                         weights = c(1, 1)), 
                    .Names = c("edges", "weights")), 
  stupid_fun = structure(list(edges = character(0), 
                              weights = numeric(0)), 
                         .Names = c("edges", "weights"))), 
  .Names = c("cool_fun", "mysum", "mydot", "myfun", "stupid_fun"))

my_graph <- graph::graphNEL(nodes=nodes, edgeL=list_edges, edgemode = "directed")

plot(my_graph)
```

Comment: Maybe plotly: https://plot.ly/r/network-graphs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other packages that let you make network graphs. Try installing and using the `visNetwork` package. They actually have an example on their main page that does exactly what you want.

Link:

http://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/